# performance two server in one machine

Tags: java, performance

i have two java server with different purpose, i had to run them in the same time in the same machine. my question is: (for performance) is better to create only one application in which instantiate two ServerSocket (with different ports) or create two different java application for each server?

Comment: for performance it is better to create only one application, but make sure it is multithreaded and capable to utilize all available processor cores.

Answer (score 3):

As always with performance issues I would advise against premature optimisation.

Perhaps deploy the solution simplest to your needs and then measure.

Note also with two servers you will have an additional process to manage, deploy, measure etc. Having two servers means you can take either down independently and/or roll each over to a separate host in case of issues. As such, I think the question relates to much more than just performance.